# Simile Timeline event times don't match actual times

Tags: timeline, simile

I'm using Simile Timeline with Sharepoint and the begin and end times are being pulled in OK according to the bubble text, but the bars for the events are being painted in the wrong places. They are all 4 hours ahead of the actual times. For instance, one event has 8:00 and 10:00 for the times, but is being painted from 12hr to 14hr. 
I think it has to do with the offset between GMT and my local time (4 hours). Any ideas about how to make it paint with no offset?

Answer (score 0):

In order to get mine to look correct, I had to omit entering the timeZone property of the bandInfo (leaving it to default) and then forcing the DateTime object to be UTC even though it isn't.  I hope that there is a better way than this, but it works.

I pull the month, day, year, and time out of the string provided by the SharePoint service and restructure them as follows for the timeline event object:

monthStr + "/" + dayStr + "/" + YearStr + " " + timeStr + " UTC";